# Can't checkout out a remote branch which has been merged on Github

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I'm having an odd issue with checking out a remote branch from Github.

Scenario:

I checked out the master branch of a repo from Github. I then created a local branch `branch_a` and made my changes. I committed the changes to `branch_a` and pushed them to Github. I created a pull request for `branch_a` which was approved, and I merged it into `master`. I didn't delete the branch after the pull request.

Later I cloned a new copy of the repo and tried to checkout `branch_a`. However, when I try to checkout the branch with `git checkout branch_a` git fails silently and I am left still on `master`. The weirdest part is that I can see that the branch exists remotely when I call `git branch -a`.

To get around this I tried creating a new local branch with the same name as `branch_a` and made some changes. I pushed these changes and was able to create another pull request for the branch. However, if I clone another copy of the repo and try to check out the repo, I have the same problem where I can't checkout the remote `branch_a` with the pending changes in the pull request.

Comment: Do you still see it after you run `git remote prune origin` which tells git to removes locally remote branches that have been removed remotely. [prune](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-empruneem)

Comment: Yeah it's still there

Comment: I can checkout a remote branch with the name `branch_a`. Is your github repo public? If it's public, can you give the link so that I can test repo with the problem you met? BTW: does it only for `branch_a` that you can't checkout or all the other remote branches you can't checkout either?

Answer (score 3):

If the branch is in the remote origin and you are trying to checkout from this remote

Run `git fetch origin branch_a` and then checkout `git checkout origin/branch_a`

Answer (score -2):

This helped me

```
git fetch --all

git checkout master

git branch new_branch

git checkout new_branch
```